# Unable to pop values from a standard object onto a custom object

Tags: email, email-template, merge

I am trying to pop up values from a Lead lookup field on a custom object in email template.

I am using the detail link {!Lead.Link} in an email template.

Please let me know how to populate values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference values from lookup or master-detail related records, you will need to create a formula field on your custom object which references the field you want.  For instance, if you want to see the Lead's email and the Lead lookup field is called "Lead__c" then create a formula field (text) on your custom object and the formula will be "Lead__r.Email".  If you call the formula field "LeadEmail__c" then you can reference it as normal in an email template: {!CustomObject__c.LeadEmail__c}.